# Not getting post data in controller from ajax

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am posting my form data to A controller but when I post data I am not getting in the controller when I call `print_r($_POST);` its returning null array I don't know what I have missed

Please let me know what inputs you want from my side

```
var data2 = [];
data2['user_firstname'] = user_firstname;
data2['user_lastname'] = user_lastname;
data2['user_phone'] = user_phone;
data2['user_email'] = user_email;
data2['user_username'] = user_username;
data2['user_password'] = user_password;
console.log(data2);

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost/shago/register/submit",
    data: { 'data2': data2 },
    // dataType: "text",
    success: function(resultData) { console.log(resultData); }
});
```

controller code

```
public function submit()
{
    print_r($_POST);
}
```

Comment: Post the laravel code too

Comment: please look updated question

Comment: try ` print_r(request()->all());`

Comment: getting blank array

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
     dump($request);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding Request as parameter on your submit function

```
public function submit(Request $request)
{
    print_r($request);
}
```

Also, do you really need to pass your information as an array?
You could just create a new object and pass that as well.

```
var data2={
'user_firstname': user_firstname,
'user_lastname': user_lastname,
'user_phone': user_phone,
'user_email': user_email,
'user_username': user_username,
'user_password': user_password
};
    $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
            'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

$.ajax({

  type: "POST",
  url: "http://localhost/shago/register/submit",
  data: data2,
  success: function(resultData) { console.log(resultData); }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to inject Request Class injection into submit method. This can help you:

```
public function submit(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request)
{
    dd($request->all()); // will print all data
}
```

of if you don't want to inject Request then this code may helps you

```
public function submit()
{
    dd(request()->all()); // will print all data
}
```

Good Luck !!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the request was intercepted by Laravel CSRF Protection policy.In order to prove it, you should add request URL in VerifyCsrfToken middleware file, like following:

`protected $except = [
        'yoururl'
    ];`

If you can get the data you expect in your controller, then I am right.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all i found error in when i am sending array data now i have modified code and its working fine 
see code

```
 $.ajax({
          url: "register/submit", 
          type: "post",
          headers: {
              'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
          },
          data: {'user_firstname':user_firstname,'user_lastname':user_lastname,'user_phone':user_phone,'user_email':user_email,'user_username':user_username,'user_password':user_password},
              success: function(result){
                 console.log(result);
                }
            });

      }
```